# Illustrator 3D extrude and bevel problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, effects, illustrator-effects

Right, sorry if the pictures are a bit small, but look at the group on the right where I'm previewing a 3D effect.

[image: Preview]

Notice how there are three turquoise stripes running along it. (You can look at the 2D version)

Basically, I change the extrude depth from 50pt to 30pt and for no reason at all, the middle turquoise shape vanishes!!

[image: Bevel Changed]

Is this a bug or what?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the 3D effect display. You can try changing the perspective by 1 degree or adjust some rotation by a minute amount.

Basically, you just have to play with minor adjustments until everything appears correctly.

Illustrator's 3D effect is "adequate" at best. It's never been wonderful.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying that. Appalling to be honest, considering this is version six and costs £30 a month.

Slight deviation, but do you know of any dedicated 3D vector programs, then?

Comment: Actually vector 3D is a tough thing to find. Swift.3D and Google SketchUp are probably the two best I've found. It is a shame Adobe doesn't address 3D in vector form a la Dimensions (from the 90s).